# Setting a groupHeaderTemplate for Kendo Grid UI

Tags: php, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm now working with kendo Grid UI with PHP. I have a column in Grid to list the 'Stage' name from my DB(a field name of a table 'stage_name'). I was able to do so by setting "stage_name" as field in the column, but I have to sort the Stage Name in basis of "stage_id" (primary key of table). So I rewritten the code as below:

```
var grid = $("#stageGrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "stage_id",  // stage_name
        title: "Stage",
        template: "#=stage_name#",
        aggregates: ["count"],
        groupHeaderTemplate: "Stage : #=(value != null)? value : 'Empty' # (Count: #=count#)",
        width: 150
    }]
});
```

I was able to list Stage Name's, Sort name's with respect to stage_id & all that. Now, my issue is that while grouping the column, stage_id's are showing up as the column header (you can see that in the image [attached](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/07a67bhud2) ). I have to fix that by showing corresponding Stage name. Can any of you have a good idea on this to help me. Expecting you valuable idea's.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you are using a foreign key column in your grid and you want to show name corresponding to that foreign key id and you also want to group by using that foreign key. To do so the best way to use values property of column which except an array of object with text and value property, Kendo gird will automatically pick the text for that row bases on the value of that column.

for more information you can check this link

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn

Here is a working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
    var positionValues = [{
      "text": "Project Manager",
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "text": "Sales Manager",
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "text": "Engineer",
      "value": 3
    }];

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [{
        field: "name",
        title: "Name"
      }, {
        field: "age",
        title: "Age"
      }, {
        field: "positionId",
        title: "Position",
        values: positionValues
      }],
      dataSource: {
        data: [{
          name: "Jane Doe",
          age: 30,
          positionId: "2"
        }, {
          name: "John Doe",
          age: 34,
          positionId: "1"
        }, {
          name: "Sam Degree",
          age: 40,
          positionId: "1"
        }, {
          name: "Salina Kile",
          age: 51,
          positionId: "2"
        }, {
          name: "Johney Doe",
          age: 24,
          positionId: "3"
        }, {
          name: "Matt Prior",
          age: 23,
          positionId: "3"
        }, {
          name: "Michael Jackson",
          age: 37,
          positionId: "2"
        }, ],
        group: {
          field: "positionId",
          aggregates: [{
            field: "age",
            aggregate: "count"
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope It will help.

**EDIT**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
    var positionValues = [{
      "text": "Project Manager",
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "text": "Sales Manager",
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "text": "Engineer",
      "value": 3
    }];

    function showPos(value) {
      position = positionValues.find(function(el){
        return el.value == value;
      });
      return (position) ? position.text : "";
    }
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [{
        field: "name",
        title: "Name"
      }, {
        field: "age",
        title: "Age"
      }, {
        field: "positionId",
        title: "Position",
        values: positionValues,
        groupHeaderTemplate: "Custom Template: #= showPos(value) #"
      }],
      dataSource: {
        data: [{
          name: "Jane Doe",
          age: 30,
          positionId: "2"
        }, {
          name: "John Doe",
          age: 34,
          positionId: "1"
        }, {
          name: "Sam Degree",
          age: 40,
          positionId: "1"
        }, {
          name: "Salina Kile",
          age: 51,
          positionId: "2"
        }, {
          name: "Johney Doe",
          age: 24,
          positionId: "3"
        }, {
          name: "Matt Prior",
          age: 23,
          positionId: "3"
        }, {
          name: "Michael Jackson",
          age: 37,
          positionId: "2"
        }, ],
        group: {
          field: "positionId",
          aggregates: [{
            field: "age",
            aggregate: "count"
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ty for the help, I will look into this & update you.

Comment: this is a helpful work but can you help me on one more thing. While doing as you suggested, I'm unable to show groupHeaderTemplate. Do you know how to set that as I show in above code.

Comment: For using groupHeaderTemplate you can use custom function to map your values with  corresponding text. Check my updated answer

Comment: I'm getting an error ReferenceError: showPos is not defined

Comment: Check above snippet showPos()  is a custom function that accept value (id) and return text (name) corresponding to that value.

Comment: Are you sure that we can call a custom function inside groupHeaderTemplate?

Comment: Yes we can call function inside template see http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.groupHeaderTemplate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130669/discussion-between-sinto-and-r-k-saini).